# Warning when deleting processors using Nifi 1.6

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi

I recently upgraded the test environment to Nifi 1.6 on Centos 7.  I am running a three node cluster using the Nifi internal zookeeper version.   If I drag in a new processor and then delete it I get the following stack trace in the logs.

```
WARN StandardStateManagerProvider Component with ID {} was removed from Nifi instance but failed to clear clustered state for the component.  
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must start with / character
   at org.apache.zookeeper.common.PathUtils.validationPath(PathUtils.java:51)
   at org.apache.zookeeper.Zookeeper.setData(ZooKeeper.java:1257).
```

Comment: Which processor(s) cause this error?

Comment: I have tried three different ones with the same results, but AttributeRollingWindow is the one I tried first